# Copying rows violates not-null constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints, auto-increment

I am trying to do what is described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344327/2075003) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062361/2075003). That means I would like to copy rows with many columns while changing only a few values. So my query looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
    SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE <conditions>;

UPDATE temp_table 
    SET <auto_inc_field>=NULL, 
        <fieldx>=<valuex>,
        <fieldy>=<valuey>;

INSERT INTO original_table SELECT * FROM temporary_table;
```

However, the `<auto_inc_field>=NULL` part is not working for me, respectively my PostgreSQL 9.4 database:

```
Exception: null value in column "auto_inc_field" violates not-null constraint
```

The `<auto_inc_field>` column is defined as BIGINT, SERIAL, and has a primary key constraint.

What do I need to pass, if `NULL` is not working? Is there an alternative method?

Comment: What is the definition of `<the aut_inc_field>`? It needs to accept null.

Comment: Updated the question. It has a primary constraint. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the primary key is a `serial`. List all columns but the primary key in the `insert` command. List the correspondent columns and values in the `select` command:

```
insert into original_table (col_1, col_2, col_3)
select col_1, value_2, value_2
from original_table
where the_conditions;
```

Comment: ok - this is the pragmatic version :D My question is asking for the elegant one ;)

Comment: @n1000 I'm not aware of a more elegant one. Are you? What is not elegant about it?

Comment: I was referring to this [question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15344327/2075003), which I couldn't get to work in my setup.