# MySQL contradiction insert

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment, select-insert

I am trying to insert into one of my tables (from the same table). I need to change 1 of the values, so I tried to insert with select as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783150/mysql-how-to-copy-rows-but-change-a-few-fields).
I have an auto increment pk, and would want the newly inserted pk to continue the count. so inserting would result into adding 1 to the pk.

```
INSERT INTO test.pp_publication_info
(id,
publication_fk,
template_fk,
allow_excel_upload)
SELECT 
id, 55, template_fk, allow_excel_upload
FROM pp_publication_info where id = "1";
```

I get a 1062 error, which is a duplicate entry for `1` for KEY PRIMARY.
I would have though that because of the AI it would +1 the ID column. SO I checked to see if I could add a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id`. Unfortunately it didn't matter where I put that in the query.

So in short: can I `INSERT` this way, with select whilst holding the AI function? If so, where am I going wrong and if not, are there any any alternatives?

Addition: create statement of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pp_publication_info` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`publication_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`template_fk` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`allow_excel_upload` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

This means the database will generate an identifier *for you* when the record is inserted.  So simply don't insert a value into that field.  It will be populated automatically.

So something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test.pp_publication_info
  (publication_fk,
   template_fk,
   allow_excel_upload)
SELECT 
  55, template_fk, allow_excel_upload
FROM pp_publication_info where id = 1;
```

After the `INSERT` is executed, you'll find that the `id` column of any new record(s) has been populated with the next value(s) in the sequence.  (Barring any gaps in the sequence, which could happen for any number of reasons.)

Comment: That slipped past. Thanks for pointing that out. Will accept this as my answer.