# SQL: How to copy rows, and also change a fields(PK)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have trouble duplicating rows from a MS Access table. [This is a table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY360.png). My (PK) in this table are BID, Order_nr, Parameter_ID and TimeStamp.

This is a query I have now, but it doesnt work; says "INSERT INTO syntax error"

```
INSERT INTO Measurement_test ( BID, Order_nr, Parameter_ID, Value, Machine_Serial_nr, TimeStamp, Passed)
SELECT  BID, '12345', Parameter_ID, Value, Machine_Serial_nr, TimeStamp, Passed
FROM Measurement_test
WHERE BID = 123;
```

I want to copy all those rows and create new rows while setting the Order_nr to 12345. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There is allready a solution for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783150/mysql-how-to-copy-rows-but-change-a-few-fields    which works for my other table, but not for this one. Please help :)

Comment: Also, if `Order_nr` is PK, it should be Unique. If your select statement returns more than one rows, (or you have already a record with Order_nr = 12345) it going to fail.

Comment: As you can see my PK consist of 4 fields combination, so when I duplicate - each new row created is unique as I give it new Order_nr. And that new Order_nr assigned doesnt exists in the table before running the query

Comment: Is Order_nr a string?

Comment: No, it is integer(number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several [Reserved Words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx) in your column names:

```
Value, TimeStamp
```

You need to enclose them with square brackets.

And if `Order_nr` is integer, don't use quotes around the value.

```
INSERT INTO Measurement_test ( BID, Order_nr, Parameter_ID, [Value], Machine_Serial_nr, [TimeStamp], Passed)
SELECT  BID, 12345, Parameter_ID, [Value], Machine_Serial_nr, [TimeStamp], Passed
FROM Measurement_test
WHERE BID = 123;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work yet. Now, first I get a message that I am about to append (1) number of rows and after clicking Yes, I get another error message which says: MS Access set 0 fields to Null due to type coversion failure , and didnt add 1 record to the table due to keys violation, 0 due to lock violations and 0 records due to validation rules violation

Comment: So as I understand, something is wrong with Primary keys

Comment: I found a mistake in my primary table, it works perfectly. THANK YOU! I give upvote, but as I am a new user, no one can see it ;/