# How to duplicate a row multiple times in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I need to duplicate a row multiple times in the same table.

I have a table like this

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFLuS.png)

I want to duplicate the second row multiple times but with increment to ID.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Write n insert statements or write 1 insert statement in a loop in a procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to copy rows, but change a few fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783150/mysql-how-to-copy-rows-but-change-a-few-fields)

Answer (score 3):

Add 'auto_increment' in property for id and:

```
INSERT INTO
    table_name (user_id, value, time, category)
SELECT
    user_id, value, time, category
FROM
    table_name 
WHERE
    id = 330;
```

if need modification table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```