# Copy all rows changing only one field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields

```
ID, date, attribute
```

I want to duplicate all of the rows but with the duplicates I want the ID to be different. The current ID is 241, I want the ID of the copied rows to be 251.

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, date, attribute) SELECT (251, date, attribute) FROM attendance WHERE ID = 241
```

as per the post here - [MySQL: How to copy rows, but change a few fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783150/mysql-how-to-copy-rows-but-change-a-few-fields)   but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not a problem description. What happens when you run it? Why is that wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have parentheses around the list of columns after `SELECT`.

Comment: You are correct Barmer. Sorry underscore_d I should have been more specific

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table temporary_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE <conditions>;

UPDATE temporary_table SET <fieldx>=<valuex>, <fieldy>=<valuey>, ...;

UPDATE temporary_table SET <auto_inc_field>=NULL;

INSERT INTO original_table SELECT * FROM temporary_table;

DROP TABLE temporary_table
```

You can try this. Its an alternative solution in the answer given to

[MySQL: How to copy rows, but change a few fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783150/mysql-how-to-copy-rows-but-change-a-few-fields)

Comment: What did you change? Why does that fix the problem? Don't just drop code without context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the parenthesis from the `SELECT`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE attendance (ID int,`date` date, attribute varchar(5))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (ID int,`date` date, attribute varchar(5))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (241,NOW(),'YES1'),(241,NOW(),'YES2'),(241,NOW(),'YES3')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 (ID, `date`, attribute) SELECT 251, `date`, attribute FROM attendance WHERE ID = 241
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
>  ID | date       | attribute
> --: | :--------- | :--------
> 251 | 2020-11-30 | YES1     
> 251 | 2020-11-30 | YES2     
> 251 | 2020-11-30 | YES3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86f121fa51fcabf57f1473bcab250419)*