# psql 15: insert ... select triggering autoincrement where NULL values

Tags: postgresql, psql, insert-select

I'm trying to "copy/paste" rows of a table with `bigserial` `id` column, without listing all columns names in the query. There is a related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344327, which does not work with psql.
The isses is that psql does not trigger auto increment, when inserting NULL values.
The minimal case is

```
CREATE TABLE src (                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    id bigserial, 
    txt text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO src ( 
    txt)          
    VALUES (      
        'a'),     
    (             
        'b'),     
    (             
        'c'),     
    (             
        'b'       
);                
                  
CREATE temp TABLE src_temp AS
SELECT            
    *             
FROM              
    src           
WHERE             
    txt = 'b';    
                  
UPDATE            
    src_temp      
SET               
    id = NULL;    
                  
INSERT INTO src   
SELECT            
    *             
FROM              
    src_temp;
```

resulting in:

> ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "src" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (null, b).

The practical case is that there are way more columns in the `src` table.

Is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct values in your `UPDATE` query. To do this you first need to find out the identifier of the sequence that works the magic of your `bigserial` column. Usually it is *tablename underscore columnname underscore 'seq'*, so for your example it would most likely be `src_id_seq`.
Then you need to modify the `UPDATE` statement so that it fills in values from this sequence instead of `NULL` using [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```
UPDATE            
    src_temp      
SET               
    id = nextval('src_id_seq');
```

Now you have valid datasets in `src_temp` that you can insert into `src`.

Note that if your tablename or columnname needs quoting, i.e. because they contain uppercase letters, you end up with an identifier for the sequence that also needs quoting like this

```
nextval('"Table_Column_seq"')
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Feel free to set an answer to "accepted" if it solved your problem. It lets other people with a similar question know that this question has a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Constraints are checked before the update and the autoincrement is triggered.
2. You are explicitly adding `NULL` to `id`. The issue is that [serial types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) add `NOT NULL` to the column definition so that constraint kicks in when the INSERT is attempted. If you want this to work do `INSERT INTO src(txt)   SELECT  txt  FROM  src_temp;`. Then the `id`  column will be populated by the `DEFAULT` value which is the`nextval()` of the sequence backing the `bigserial` type.

```
CREATE TABLE src (                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    id bigserial, 
    txt text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO src ( 
    txt)          
    VALUES (      
        'a'),     
    (             
        'b'),     
    (             
        'c'),     
    (             
        'b'       
);                
                  
CREATE temp TABLE src_temp AS
SELECT            
    *             
FROM              
    src           
WHERE             
    txt = 'b';    
                  
UPDATE            
    src_temp      
SET               
    id = NULL;    
                  
INSERT INTO src(txt)   
SELECT            
    txt
FROM              
    src_temp;
INSERT 0 2

select * from src;
 id | txt 
----+-----
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
  4 | b
  5 | b
  6 | b
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way I fall back in the undesired need to listing columns in last `INSERT INTO src(**txt**)`.

Comment: Well that is what you are going to have to do.  A way to get a column list, in `psql`: `\pset format csv` then ` select * from <table_name> limit 0;` then back to `\pset format aligned`. This will get you a comma separated list of column names from which you can delete the `serial` column.