# Primary key with multiple columns, with one being auto-incremental

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to alter a table as to add another newly created column being part of the already existing primary key (that includes multiple columns) and this newly created column (`id`) should auto-increment and also have a default value. Basically, any query inserting data in the table should be able to ignore `id` in the query and I'd like the first row to have an `id` of 1.

Here's the script creating the table initially

```
<createTable tableName="thetable">
            <column name="col1" type="SMALLINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_thetable"/>
            </column>
            <column name="col2" type="SMALLINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_thetable"/>
            </column>
            <column name="col3" type="SMALLINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_thetable"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
```

And here's the script trying to add a new column the the PK.

```
<dropPrimaryKey  tableName="thetable" constraintName="pk_thetable"/>

<addColumn tableName="thetable">
    <column name="id" type="SMALLINT" autoIncrement="true" startWith="1">
        <constraints nullable="true" />
    </column>
</addColumn>

<addPrimaryKey tableName="thetable" columnNames="col1,col2,col3,id" 
         constraintName="pk_thetable"/>
```

The script runs fine, but in the end, INSERT's have to provide the `id` when inserting data in the table. Is this even possible in PGSQL terms or it's my script that needs tweaking ?

I've tried both with a nullable or non-nullable `id` already.

Comment: Take a look at this [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76893784/3422102) A similar approach in your case may satisfy the `id` constraint as well.